# Is it possible to keep the integers in a float64 column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a way to read a float column in pandas data frame and keep the integers without the float character (for example the dot)?

Example:

I have a csv and I got

```
0           0.0
1         0.555
2        0.2323
3           0.0
4           50.0
```

but I want to get

```
0           0
1         0.555
2        0.2323
3           0
4           50
```

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: No (unless you convert everything to string). Column in a dataframe can only be of one type.

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Hi @Andreas it is to check if exists float number in a supposed integer column

Comment: Why is dtype float if it is supposed to be int column then?

Comment: Because it is a file uploaded from an user and i have to make sure that a column only has int

Comment: But in your expected values there are still 2 floats?

Answer (score 2):

Modify pandas `display.float_format` option with the desired format:

```
import pandas

pandas.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: f"{x:g}")

df = pandas.DataFrame([1.1, 1.0, 2.0, 153, 2.2])
print(df)
```

Results in:

```
    0
0 1.1
1   1
2   2
3 153
4 2.2
```

Note that this only changes **display** format. Underlying data type is still float, as the columns in dataframes need to have the same type.